# Transparent text with wideImage lib?

Tags: php

I am using http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/ with PHP and I would like to write text on image which will be transparent in about 50%. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but requires you to retrieve the TrueColor version of the image:

```
$image = $image->asTrueColor();
```

Once that is done, you can simply do the following to write text with 50% alpha transparency:

```
$color = $image->allocateColorAlpha(255, 255, 255, 63);
$canvas = $image->getCanvas();
$canvas->useFont('path/to/font.ttf', 16, $color);
$canvas->writeText('right', 'bottom', 'Hello, world!');
```

Comment: There's no need to define a custom operation for this, WideImage_TrueColorPalette already has allocateColorAlpha() method: http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/wp-content/current/doc/WideImage/WideImage_TrueColorImage.html#methodallocateColorAlpha

The example is otherwise correct.

Comment: @gasper_k: Forgot about `WideImage_TrueColorImage`. Modified.

Comment: And if you already have a WideImage_TrueColorImage instance (which is always the case with JPEG, and highly likely with PNG), you don't even have to call the asTrueColor() method. :)

Comment: @gasper_k: Unfortunately, in an image upload script, you can't be guaranteed that.